# Populate a c# object with random values

Tags: c#

I want to populate an object with random data at runtime.

There are lots of tools (like nBuilder) but the rely on generics and I don't know the object's type until runtime.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** This has nothing to do with testing or test data. I have a WCF Service, and for any data contract type I want to deserialize it to XML and JSON and display the output. The deserialized output can then be used by other developers and testers as a reference guide.

If the object is not populated the deserialized output is not meaningful.

I don't want to build proxies, or use WSDL etc.

I got nBuilder working with reflection. But its only populating value types?

Comment: Could you provide us with an example? It's very hard to answer this without more information.

Comment: Invoke nBuilder with reflection?

Comment: Isn't it quite unusual to not know the type until runtime in a statically typed language as C#? Unless you are using `dynamic` that is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any tools to populate class properties with random data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413342/are-there-any-tools-to-populate-class-properties-with-random-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically for reference guides devs will want something more than just random data.  It always helps their understanding if you use something close to real world data.

With that in mind I would highly recommend that you add something like a .Example() call (or something like that) which would let the object itself emit some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your after some kind of mocking framework.

Eg [MOQ](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart) or [Rhino Mocks](http://www.ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have Expression Blend or Visual Studio Database Edition, both of these tools can generate sample data for you.

If not, you can try something like is described [on this blog post](http://www.williablog.net/williablog/post/2010/07/30/Random-Sample-Data-Generator.aspx).

You can also grab some of the SQL sample databases like Northwind / Adventure Works and use that data to populate your objects if it's suitable.