# How do I generate test data?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class, is there a way to quickly generate a lot of objects from this class with random data?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625490/c-sharp-library-to-populate-object-with-random-data and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413342/are-there-any-tools-to-populate-class-properties-with-random-data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

user reflection to go through all properties and set random value to it.
somethig like this

```
object classObject;
PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos;
propertyInfos = typeof(classObject).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
{
     propertyInfo.SetValue(classObject, value, null)
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can generate test data using [NBuilder](http://nbuilder.org/)

Through a fluent, extensible interface, NBuilder allows you to rapidly create test data, automatically assigning values to properties and public fields that are of type of the built in .NET data types (e.g. ints and strings).

Answer (score 5):

You may checkout [AutoFixture](http://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture).

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio has inbuilt support for test data generation. This is targetted at database population, but once in a database it would be easy to do a little code generation.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193262.aspx